# Screen's width is different than it should be on mobile

Tags: html, css, reactjs, sass

I'm having this problem: I did not set any width on my root element, I deleted everything I had from my HTML elements, yet it still sets root's width to 980px even though you can clearly see on the screenshot that it's not the real width. What is more if i resize it a little, it still says its 980px... And so it goes on every size up to 980px width.

I tried setting its width to calc(100vw) - without success, only setting it with pixels actually changes it, but that's not what I want obviously. It bothers me a lot because my mixins on min-screen won't work properly because of that.

Am I really doing something wrong here? I don't understand... Any help/explaination would be nice.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'd doing it right.

Don't trust Chrome's responsive design mode. I is giving you the @2x dimensions.

Comment: You're right... I ust checked on Mozilla and it works just fine. Is there any reason for that? An update or anything? Because I've been working on Chrome while doing responsive views for a while now and I've never experienced it before

Comment: The idea is that some browsers on mobile devices report 320px wide when it is really 640px (higher resolution). I guess this feature is supposed to make it easier to work with raster graphics. I've never found it helpful, though.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation!